# Maps printing one by one and not in one row using ggmap loop mfrow

Tags: r, loops, ggmap

When using this code i was hoping to get all the print to appear on one row. Instead they print one by one.

Can anyone spot my error??

```
par(mfrow=c(1,8))
(e<-bbox(extent(data3)))
m <- get_map(e, zoom=11, source="google", maptype = "terrain")

# 
# for(i in 1:length(subs10_latlong)) # all periods
for(i in 2:8) # Not first and last period
{
  # subs10_latlong.df <- as(subs10_latlong[[i]], "data.frame")
  m <- get_map(e, zoom=11, source="google", maptype = "terrain")
  p <- (ggmap(m) + geom_point(data=as(subs10_latlong[[i]], "data.frame"), aes(x=location.long, y=location.lat, colour = trackId)))
  print(p)
  }
```

Comment: You need to use `gridExtra::grid.arrange`. You're mixing base graphics and grid graphics and that won't work as expected.

Comment: ok. Where exactly would I put that into the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
lapply(2:8, function(i) {

  m <- get_map(e, zoom=11, source="google", maptype = "terrain")
  p <- ggmap(m) 
  p <- p + geom_point(data=as(subs10_latlong[[i]], "data.frame"), 
                      aes(x=location.long, y=location.lat, colour = trackId))
  p

}) -> gplots

do.call(grid.arrange, c(gplots, ncol=8))
```

to mimic your `par` settings.

Comment: DID work. An additional output wind was open in the background!